# Normalization of Table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, normalization, database-normalization

I am trying to create a simple Registration Program using VB.Net and MySQL for its database. Here's my simple table for the basic Information

[image]

However, I am attempting to improve my basic knowledge in normalization of table and that's why I separated the Date field to avoid, let say in one day, the repeated insertion of the same date. I mean, when 50 individuals registered in one day, it will simply add a single date(record) in tblRegDate table instead of adding it up for 50 times in a table. Is there any way to do this? Is it possible in VB.Net and MySQL? Or rather, should I add or modify some field? or should I make a condition in VB.Net? The table above is what my friend taught me but I discovered that it doesn't eliminate the redundancy. Kindly give me any instruction or direct me to site where there's a simple tutorial for this. Thanks in advance!

here's my MySQL codes:

```
CREATE TABLE tblInfo(
       Number INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
       LastName VARCHAR(45),
       FirstName VARCHAR(45),
       MiddleName VARCHAR(45),
       Gender ENUM(M,F),
       BirthDate DATE,
       PRIMARY KEY(Number));

CREATE TABLE tblRegDate(
       IDRegDate INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
       Date TIMESTAMP,
       Number INT,
       PRIMARY KEY(IDRegDate),
       FOREIGN KEY(Number) REFERENCES tblInfo(Number));
```

Comment: I think you should just keep your `RegDate` field in the info table.

Comment: The storage required for one DATE column in the `tblInfo` table would be about the same size as the storage for the foreign key value, so the space saving is minimal; the cost of joining with the `tblRegDate` table outweighs any saving.  The technique is not necessarily automatically bad; this is just not a compelling example of using the technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it in this case you don't have advanages of seperating a single field. You'll loose a lot of performance.

Table normalization isn't about don't having any redundant value. It's more about "Seperating the concerns"

Also it is important to not have an exploding complexity in your database. seperating single fills would end up in a database no one would be able to understand.

The Question is: Are there more informations on registration ? For Example Webpage, IP, .....

Than you should have two tables for example "Person" and "Registration". Then you would have two semantic different things which shouldn't be mixed up.

There are a lot of examples and information you can find via google. and wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thanks... your answer is of help to me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not a good idea to seperate timestamp from the table. 
You would need another table namely i.e timeTable. It would have two columns id and timestmap and you should reference this id in your tblRegDate table as foreign key.
Foreign key is an integer and has the size 4 bytes. Date on the other hand 3 bytes.

Therefore I would recommend you to keep date in your tblRegDate and not in a extra table

Answer (score 1):

When you normalize DB structures, always keep it mind of ACID - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Based on the fields you have, you should just keep it as a single table.  Separating out the registration date is not a good design because you'll have to do a look up every time.  In real life, you can consider indexing the reg date if your app always search or sort by regdate.

And if you FK RegDate table to the user table, it is also not efficient.

p.s. Also keep in mind that there are 4 levels of DB normalization.  If you are new to DB design, you should consider learning how to move a DB design from 1st to 2nd, and 2nd to 3rd normal forms.

We rarely use 4th normal form in real life situation.  Transaction systems usually stay at 3rd most of the time.

Hope that make sense.

Comment: There are (at least) SIX numbered Normal Forms, not four. There are also others such as BCNF, DKNF and EKNF. 5th Normal Form is quite probably the most common in actual use.